# Child div ignoring parent element padding-bottom in Firefox but working on chrome

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

Why firefox (desktop and android) ignoring `padding-bottom`. ?

It's working fine with `padding-top` but not with padding-bottom.

**Firefox**

[image: Firefox]

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/frh3v1zu/)

Comment: I don't see how its not working. I put padding-bottom: 200px and its working as expected.

Comment: @Cyclotron3x3 see the screen shot its not working

Comment: why my question is on hold ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not ideal, but you can just use `padding-bottom: 50px` to your `.list` element, and remove it from `.parent`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frh3v1zu/2/)

Comment: upvote but why its not taking .parent padding is it bug ?

Comment: I think, it is because your `<ul>` element has greater height than your `.parent` element, so I assume, it is a bug.